# Request re-input from user if input is not integer

Tags: python, valueerror

```
While True:
    n=turtle.textinput(“”,”write your grade”)
    grade = int(n)

    while int(n) != grade :
        n=turtle.textinput(“”,”use only number”)
        grade = int(n)

    If grade <=100 and grade>=95 :
        print(“A+“)
    else :
        print(“F”)
```

I'm getting value error.

I want to get situation <- if users gives me literal answer, I want to say "only number".

Comment: `int(n)!=?` Not equal to what? Try this, `n.isalpha()` to check `n` contains alphabets!

Comment: With want do you comapre int(n) because at the moment you compare it with "nothing"

Comment: I think you mean to do something like `try: int(n) except ValueError: doSomething`

Comment: Will the inner loop get executed in any way? You set them equal before loop and the very next line check the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to try this

```py
def enforce_int(x):
    try:
        _ = int(x)
        return True
    except ValueError as _:
        return False

While True: # why is this here though?
    n=turtle.textinput(“”,”write your grade”)

    while not enforce_int(n):
        n=turtle.textinput(“”,”use only number”)

    grade = int(n)
    If grade <=100 and grade>=95 :
        print(“A+“)
    else :
        print(“F”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time please format your code in ASCII.

```
while True:
    n = input("write your grade: ")
    while True:
        try:
            grade = int(n)
            break
        except:
            n=input("use only number: ")

    if grade <=100 and grade>=95 :
        print("A+")
    else :
        print("F")
```